# html tags in DB entry not rendering as html

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ckeditor

I have a form with a notes section that uses [ckeditor](https://ckeditor.com) so that paragraphs are separated when  submitted to a MySQL database. so two paragraphs would submit as follows:

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

My problem is when this data is displayed on a webpage the HTML tags are not being read as HTML as I expected them too. When I view the page in Dev Tools it is showing quote marks outside the first and last HTML tag like below. which indicates the tags are seen as text.

```
“<p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2</p>”
```

I am doing the same on another website but this time is working fine and is rendering the HTML tags properly. When I view this in Dev Tools it shows quote marks inside the HTML tags of each paragraph like below. No surprise then the tags are being seen as HTML.

```
<p>”Paragraph 1”</p><p>”Paragraph 2”</p>
```

The Difference between the two is the one that displays properly is ‘mediumtext’ type, and the one that doesn’t is ‘text’ type. Plus the one that doesn’t display properly is using the ckeditor plugin.

I am simply using the following to add the ckeditor function:

```
<textarea rows='4' type="text"  class="notes_c" id="notes_c" 
name="notes_c" value=""></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace('notes_c');
</script>
```

Any help to understand what is happening here is much appreciated.

Update to this is i've tried using html_entity_decode with the following:

```
<?php 
$note = $rsCurrentEnquiry->getColumnVal("notes_c"); 
$p = html_entity_decode($note);
?>
<?php echo $p; ?>
```

Which solves the issue!!

Comment: This has nothing to do with mediumtext vs text, those are just text data types of different max length. More likely this has to do with how exactly that database content is output into the page.

Comment: What @04FS said! Also, it can have something to do with how you're using ckeditor, are you using the setData() method?

Comment: Thanks @04FS for your response. All I am doing is querying the database and displaying it as follows:

`<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td class="details"><?php echo ($rsCurrentEnquiry->getColumnVal('notes_c')); ?></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>`

Comment: Thanks @H. Figueiredo for your response.  All I have done is use a basic install of the plugin to use its function. I have checked the documentation and I’m not sure I  how I could use the setData() method to help with the issue.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted more of your code (specifically the javascript). setData() is method that recieves a string and fills the CKeditor with the string (it respects html tags, so they should be in effect)

Comment: apologies @H. Figueiredo for not showing code. I have edited original post to show use of ckeditor

Answer (score 1):

So, I've created a fiddle for you, of what I think you intended.

Notably you should get/set the data from CKeditor with these methods (when getting/setting data dynamically, of course):

```
CKEDITOR.instances.notes_c.getData();
CKEDITOR.instances.notes_c.setData(data_string);
```

`notes_c` - is the id/name/class of the div where CKeditor is.

If have any other question, feel free to ask.

**EDIT:** the fiddle link was broken, its fixed now. Also added another button to show both getData and setData.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fc1dawLt/)

**EDIT2:** Sorry, I had indeed misunderstood your question. So, using javascript, I would use AJAX to receive the data from your DB (`<p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2</p>`) and then do something like what I do in this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rsb709f3/)

Do note that by using PHP, if an HTML tag is incorrectly closed, or malformed, before the text you want to insert, then the PHP will append to the badly formed HTML and could interpret your string as only a string, ignoring the HTML tags inside.

Comment: No prob! I would appreciate if you marked the answer as correct if it suited your needs.

Comment: you use a button which calls the function with `onclick` which places an instance of notes_c into `<div id="output">`. I'm not sure how I can adapt this. I have the textarea with ckeditor submitting to database. then I query the database and display the data in a table `<tbody> <tr> <td class="details"><?php echo ($rsCurrentEnquiry->getColumnVal('notes_c')); ?></td> </tr> </tbody>` where or how can I apply the function to this?

Comment: Oh! You want the retrieved text inside a table? Hum, so each paragraph is a column? Or just each cell will have a value from ckeditor?

Comment: I think the fact its in a table might be misleading. its just for style purposes as it is with other tables using different data bindings from the same query. If you see my sample above. you'll see the table displaying the notes_c binding is a single row with a single column. so the `<td>` tag displaying the data could also be a `<div>` and the issue would be the same I think. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, it made sense, check edit2! What you're saying is making me think your problem is malformed HTML, like a unclosed tag, your something of that sort.

Comment: Also, in my fiddle, if I didn't have <table> tag enclosing the <tbody> (like in your comment) the browser wouldn't consider that as valid table and as such wouldn't let me put the text inside. I think this is probably not your problem, but something worth checking out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189214/discussion-between-steve-joiner-and-h-figueiredo).

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem. I've solved it by manually converting the escape code to the normal characters.